# Is JavaScript Calling Function that calls function2, same as calling function2 directly?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I believe that the following is true:

```
function outerFunc(innerFunc) {
  return innerFunc;
}
outerFunc();
```

is the same as

```
innerFunc();
```

Assuming that innerFunc is a JavaScript function.

First question.  If so, is this always true? Is there some programming principle (Identity?) that makes it so?

Comment: did you mean `return innerFunc();`? And `outerFunc(innerFunc);`, plus maybe not reusing the same name?

Comment: If I change return innerFunc to return innerFunc() then is my supposition correct?

Comment: @bob, why no sense?

Comment: @Pete only if you're not using closure.

Comment: @CodeManiac closures are from a function's creation, not from a call. This question is imho still very unclear, due to a lot of oddities in the code (we may be talking about different scenarios, due to different assumptions about how the question is intended). Apart from that, related to closures, there is no difference, whether you pass a function around and then call it, or call it directly (again neglecting `this`, and potential edge cases, which would only stem from absurd language abuse)

Comment: @ASDFGerte totally agreed, but w.r.t first snippet, i considered user wanted to create a function there and return that function instead of just calling. To more precise the code at present has no clear way to find out things, in first snippet op expects arguments in outerFunc but doesn't even pass one, so if calls that innerFunc should run into an error `undefined is not a function` 

Answer (score 0):

So if you call `outerFunc()` then it will return a function `innerFunc()`. To call `innerFunc()` from `outerFunc` you would do the following

```js
let inner = outerFunc()
inner()

// OR

outerFunc()()
```

You can confirm this behavior

```
function innerFunc(){
    console.log('inner')
}

function outerFunc(){
    console.log('outer')
    return innerFunc;
}

// Calling outerfunc would onkly print out 'outer'
outerFunc()
/*
console.log('outer')
*/

// Calling the returned function from outerFunc prints out 'outer' and 'inner'
outerFunc()()
/*
console.log('outer')
console.log('inner')
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a paradigm called [Javascript Function Closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp).

Follows an example for your case:

```js
function innerFunc() {
   console.log("innerFunc");
}

function outerFunc(innerFunc) {
  return this.innerFunc;
}

outerFunc()();

// It's equals to

innerFunc();
```

Comment: Why you magically dig out a `this`, produce code that does something completely different than what is expected, and won't work in strict mode, is beyond me. You also copied OP's flaw of `outerFunc` taking a parameter (with the same name as a global function, nice shadowing), yet calling it without one (it's never used anyways). What all of this has to do with closures is also a mystery to me.